# Orthogonal projection in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, orthonormal, projection

Projector $P\neq0$ is orthogonal projection if and only if satisfied some of the following mutually equivalent conditions:

a) $P$ is self-adjoint, $P=P^*$

b) $P$ is normal, i.e. $P^*P=PP^*$

c) $P$ is positive

d) $\|P\|=1$

By definition, if $P\neq 0$ is orthogonal projector that is equivalent with a).

$a)\implies b):$ $P^*P=P^2=PP^*$

$a)\iff c):$ $P$ is positive if it's square form is nonnegative. That is equivalent with $\langle Pf,f\rangle$ is real. Operator is self adjoint iff it's square form is real.

Can anyone give me a hint how to prove rest of implications.

Comment: Topology and Modern Analysis by George Simmons is a good reference for this. The proofs are somewhat long and the result is available in many books. Your proof of a) iff c) is not correct.

Comment: In the mentioned book I couldn't find the proofs. Can you tell me other references?